# How do I make my global.js file talk to Jade?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have a global javascript file where I'm reading some data from a database.

```
//globals.js
var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];

//Populate Info Box
$('#carInfoReg').text(thisUserObject.reg);
$('#carPhoto').source(thisUserObject.LinkImage);
```

The content of `thisUserObject.LinkImage` is a link (properly formatted with "http://") and I want to use that  to set the source attribute of an image tag in my jade file.

```
br
  strong Photo
  img(src='#{carPhoto}')
```

however it's not displaying anything at all.

What am I doing wrong? How can I talk to jade with data from my globals.js file?

Comment: Is your global js run on node or browser?

Comment: browser. it's within a javascript function declaration.

Comment: And your jade is rendered by express?

Comment: When jade is compiled, it becomes a plain html files. You may need a mv framework like vue if you need a lot bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Once jade is compiled, it has nothing to do with jade anymore. If you just want it to work, [vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/index.html) is the best choice. It's very intuitive.
Jade:

```
script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js")
#app
  br
  strong Photo
  img(src='{{carPhoto}}')
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        imgSrc: "http:www.foo.com",
        carInfoReg: " This carInfoReg "
    }
});
// it is easy to manipulate the data inside vue.
//when you update data of Vue instance, its view will be updated automatically.
vm.imgSrc = "http://www.bar.com/dwagsgd";
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okv0rgrk/3952/)